# VIM create new file from nerdtree but then key mapping fail to work

Tags: python, vim, nerdtree

I have got key mapping

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

and when I press `<F9>` it can call up python to execute current file.

I have NerdTree Plugin can copy a new file from `m` then `c`, rename the new file.

Everything works fine besides function key, when I press `<F9>` nothing happened.

But when I use `!python filename.py` then it will call up python to execute function again.

May I ask why?

Comment: It's a `<buffer>` mapping, so... where exactly do you have it? What does "copy new file from `m` then `c`" mean? Where does `<F9>` not work? Is it the same buffer you have it defined for? Could you paste the relevant code that sets up the mapping and the nerdtree plugin?

Comment: Hello, key mapping is defined in ./vimrc file.  when I said copy new file, I mean press m in nerdtree to call up menu then press c to copy and rename file under same directory. F9 is to execute via python

Comment: When I say "where do you have it", I meant "Is it part of an autocommand", since defining a buffer mapping at the time when no buffers are loaded yet is not very useful. I still don't understand what you're asking, what the flow of your actions is, and what the desired outcome is, and how NerdTree copying fits with executing a Python file. Can you edit your file with step-by-step instructions to reproduce what you're doing?

Comment: Thank you very much. It is not autocommand. My purpose of using F9 is when I finish a python.py file, I press F9 to execute instead of typing !python everytime. But when I want to make a new document, I open NerdTree, then call up NerdTree menu then either copy or create a new node from there. I rename the file as ***.py but then I realised I cannot use F9 anymore.